# Making duplicate pages in a pdf - one planner page into 60 pages

Tags: linux, pdf

I have a daily planner page in a pdf file. I want to duplicate that page 60 times so that I have a pdf with 60 identical pages.

How can I do this in the terminal?

This seems like it should be easy, but my google-fu is simply failing to find something.

Worst comes to worse, I can use a for loop to create 60 copies of the pdf file and then using pdfunite to combine them, but that seems silly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

`cpdf in.pdf 60DUPall -o out.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

I advice to use `qpdf`:

```bash
qpdf in.pdf --pages $(perl -e "print '. ' x 60") -- out.pdf
```

In contrast to `cpdf`, `qpdf` is *[open source](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/blob/main/LICENSE.txt)*.

Answer (score -1):

This is a silly way I figured out how to do it, and move on with my life. Would be curious to know of a better way:

with pdfunite, there is no reason you can't supply the same argument over and over again. Here I just do it 30 times to get a 30 page pdf.

```
pdfunite a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf a.pdf output.pdf
```